# ROS and Intel Edison

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Anyone know if ROS can be installed on Intel Edison?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205005/ros-and-intel-edison/) by [Gunnlaugur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21667/gunnlaugur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you Google there are number of projects to run ROS on `Edison` found:

- http://wiki.ros.org/Edison and http://wiki.ros.org/wiki/edison.
- Also [this one](http://qiita.com/yoneken/items/eda0bedec847761088c1) is elaborated but in Japanese

(TODO: those two pages on ros.org above are currently disjoint. They should be combined or at least moved to somewhere common).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gunnlaugur](https://answers.ros.org/users/21667/gunnlaugur/) on 2015-03-14**:
@130s, Thank you - these links will be helpful.
When I googled, I only came across instructions on how to install ROS on Yocto.